# Airflow operator to copy many files (directory, prefix) from Google Cloud Storage bucket to local filesystem

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow

There is an Airflow operator [`GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_local.py#L30) to copy ONE file from GCS bucket to the local filesystem. But it supports only one file and it is not possible to copy many files for a given prefix.

There is a reverse operator [`LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/local_to_gcs.py#L31) that allows to copy many files from local filesystem to the bucket, you do it simply with the star in the path "/*".

Do you know what is the best way to copy files by the prefix from a bucket to the local filesystem in Airflow? Am I missing something or it is not just implemented for some reason?

The solution I came up so far is compressing the files before putting it to the bucket, download as one file with airflow and unzip with `BashOperator` locally. I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully copy multiple files from GCS bucket to local filesystem(mapped) for a given prefix in Airflow using the below approach.

```python
import datetime

from airflow import models
from airflow.operators import bash
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.gcs import GCSHook
from airflow.operators import python


YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
BUCKET_NAME = 'qpalzm-bucket'
GCS_FILES = ['luffy.jpg', 'zoro.jpg']
LOCAL_PATH = '/home/airflow/gcs/data'
PREFIX = 'testfolder'

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Composer Example',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
}
#
with models.DAG(
        'multi_copy_gcs_to_local',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1)) as dag:

    def multi_copy(**kwargs):
        hook = GCSHook()

        for gcs_file in GCS_FILES:
            #initialize file name and the local directory where it will be copied
            filename = f'{LOCAL_PATH}/{gcs_file}'
            
            #check if PREFIX is available and initialize the gcs file to be copied
            if PREFIX:
                object_name = f'{PREFIX}/{gcs_file}'
            
            else:
                object_name = f'{gcs_file}'

            #perform gcs hook download
            hook.download(
                bucket_name = BUCKET_NAME,
                object_name = object_name,
                filename = filename
            )

    #execute multi_copy method
    multi_copy_op = python.PythonOperator(
            task_id='multi_gcs_to_local',
            provide_context=True,
            python_callable=multi_copy,
            )

    multi_copy_op
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I will learn more about GCSHook, looks like a very useful thing